# Alamofire and Reachability.swift not working on xCode8-beta5

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, reachability, swift3, xcode8

I have a custom CocoaPod created in swift2.3 and it has Alamofire and Reachability libraries inside the project. I mean I did integrate Alamofire and Reachability into the project manually.

It still works perfectly on xCode7.3.1 and I am going to update it to swift3 on xCode8-Beta5. I tried to update it but I couldn't get it done successfully.

Here is how I did for the update.

- Replaced Alamofire and Reachability in the project folder for swift3 from 
  https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift3
- Opened xCode8-Beta5 and converted all files to Swift3 syntax(actually xCode asks it when opening the old version project). So the converting was done automatically by xCode.
- And I tried to build the Cocoapod but it gives a the bunch of error.

How can I solve this problem and update the Cocoapod successfully?

I tried to update two Cocoapods on xCode8-beta6 but Alamofire is still not working. Here is a screenshot.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gm8ud67qc1ixffb/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-20%20at%2011.06.31%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: You should update to beta 6

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for your tip. 
I updated to beta 6 but Alamofire still has issues. It means Alamofire isn't updated to Swift3 yet?

Comment: Probably not, Swift 3 still in beta, if you need reachability i can show  you an updated version

Comment: @LeoDabusI think I updated reachability to be compatible with Swift 3 but Alamofire is still not working. Do you have Alamofire updated?
I can attach the screenshot that shows the errors in updating Alamofire.

Comment: If you are going to supply code, that code must be posted here, not some third-party site that can change or disappear tomorrow and definitely not an image requiring those wanting to help to type it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to convert your code into **swift 3**, and to develop in the latest XCode 8 Beta 6 (forget to use Beta 5, I was trying to success round a clock and finally in Beta 6 it is possible to use Alamofire without rewriting all their code):

You need to update the **Alamofire** to its **4.0 version**. I was waiting for this version neverending weeks between beta 2 and beta 6, as it wasn't able to use Alamofire at all. Apple ischanging SDK version by version during summer, but now the latest branch of this framework is on github. 
In your Podfile you need to set more parameters to be able to use update stuff in these beta times. They are hardworking on **swift3 branch**.

If you don't use 4.0 version, there are many issues that XCode is not able to resolve in its convertor for its previous versions of Alamofire.
Huge amount of code they had to change.

They announced they will produce official 4.0 version after Apple releases GM seed. So until we get XCode GM Seed, put this to your Podfile before its install:

[image]

Comment: So now it's only available as a branch. One thing I forgot to mention, minimum deployment target for your project has to bet to 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

I could build Alamofire and Reachability frameworks successfully on xCode8-beta6 without any problem from the following branches.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift3
https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/tree/feature/ios10